# How to add Spacing in between icons but they remain in the same row with minimalistic code with out adding styles.js or anything like that

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

How to add Padding in between icons but they remain in the same row with minimalistic code with out adding styles.js or anything like that

```
<Card.Body>
       <a href={item.facebookPage}><Button  > <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x "></i></Button></a>
       <a href={item.instagram}><Button variant='warning'> <i  class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x" ></i></Button></a>
       <a href={item.twitter}><Button variant='primary' > <i  class="fab fa-twitter fa-3x" ></i></Button></a>
       <a href={item.youtube}><Button variant='danger' > <i  class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x" ></i></Button></a>
        <a href={item.linkedIn}><Button variant='light' > <i  class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-3x" ></i></Button></a>
  </Card.Body>
```

Currently they look like that
[image: Current Status]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above Answer is fine But I wanted to Achieve it with minimalistic Code
So By adding `className='mx-2'` inside the button, that did the job .

```
  <Card.Body>
     <a href={item.facebookPage}><Button className='mx-2' > <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x "></i></Button></a>
     <a href={item.instagram}><Button variant='warning' className='mx-2'> <i  class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x" ></i></Button></a>
     <a href={item.twitter}><Button variant='primary' className='mx-2'> <i  class="fab fa-twitter fa-3x" ></i></Button></a>
     <a href={item.youtube}><Button variant='danger' className='mx-2'> <i  class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x" ></i></Button></a>
     <a href={item.linkedIn}><Button variant='light' className='mx-2'> <i  class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-3x" ></i></Button></a>
       </Card.Body  >
```

Now they Look like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hey can't get that you want margin or padding, I mean want to get space between icons and borders or directly icons but i will tell you both.

If you want to seperate icons with some space you can use this in your css file or style tag in your html

```
Card.Body a{
   display:inline-block;
   margin-right:1em;
}
```

If you want to add padding to your icons you can use

```
Card.Body a{
   display:inline-block;
   padding:0.5em;
}
```

or

```
Card.Body a{
   display:inline-block;
   padding-left:0.5em;
   padding-right:0.5em;
}
```

But careful about padding. It may cause smaller icons in some conditions. Hope works.

Comment: Thanx for answering

Comment: But I Found another solution from `bootstrap docs`  and I posted as Answer, you can check it out.

Comment: Exactly, it will give margin both of the sides of icons like we did. It's more practical and best practice to use this bootstrap features.

Answer (score 1):

To get spacing **between** the items but not affect the spacing before or after you can make use of CSS first and last-child pseudo classes.

This snippet puts 2em spacing between the elements by giving the middle elements margin left and right 1em each and the first element only a right margin and the last element only a left margin:

```css
cardbody a {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
cardbody a:first-of-type {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
cardbody a:last-of-type {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<cardbody>
       <a href={item.facebookPage}><Button  > <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x "></i></Button></a>
       <a href={item.instagram}><Button variant='warning'> <i  class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x" ></i></Button></a>
       <a href={item.twitter}><Button variant='primary' > <i  class="fab fa-twitter fa-3x" ></i></Button></a>
       <a href={item.youtube}><Button variant='danger' > <i  class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x" ></i></Button></a>
        <a href={item.linkedIn}><Button variant='light' > <i  class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-3x" ></i></Button></a>
</cardbody>
```

Note: I could not get the format Card.Body to work as a tag with or without react so have simplified it to cardbody for the purposes of this demo.

Comment: thank you for answering but I found another way and posted the answer as well,  in very simplistic way